# Drawing shapes with "+,-,|" in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, drawing, shapes

My homework is making shapes with "+,-,|"

I have to do this :

```
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
```

But I saw this in the output :

```
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
```

Here is my code :

```
public class Method {

        void MakingShapes()
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {

                    for (int i = 0; i <=9; i++) {

                        if(i%3==0)
                        {
                            System.out.print("+");
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            System.out.print("-");
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.print("\n");

                    for (int i = 0; i <=9; i++) {

                        if(i%3==0)
                        {
                            System.out.print("|");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("");

                }
            }
        }
```

I know that my fault is in loops but I can not find it,but it looks like in the last loop.
Thank you.

Comment: You have to make the last loop iteration a special case.  All of the other iterations display `+` lines followed by `|` lines, but the last one is a `+` line **not** followed by a `|` line.  You'll need something like `if (j < 3)` or `if (j != 3)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could make it much clearer by using separate methods:

```
  private void verticalLine() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {

      if (i % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.print("|");

      } else {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
    }
    System.out.println("");
  }

  private void horizontalLine() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {

      if (i % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.print("+");
      }

      else {
        System.out.print("-");
      }
    }

    System.out.print("\n");
  }
```

Your method becomes:

```
  void MakingShapes() {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
      horizontalLine();
      verticalLine();
    }
  }
```

and it is really obvious that you just need an extra horizontalLine() call after the loop to close out the display. As pointed out in a comment by @JamesC.TaylorIV, to get the target output you also need to reduce the loop to only running three times:

```
  void MakingShapes() {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      horizontalLine();
      verticalLine();
    }
    horizontalLine();
  }
```

Comment: You would only want the loop to run 3 times for this one, should be `j < 3;` otherwise he would have a extra row in his output.

Comment: @JamesC.TaylorIV Correct, thanks. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your outer loop running 4 times.  It will execute the inner contents 4 times, which causes the for loop printing the `|` characters an extra time.  Try adding a condition to you `|` loop that makes sure it runs 1 time less than the outer loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <=9 && j < 3; i++)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is *awful* style.  If you want to avoid running the loop if `j >= 3`, put the loop inside `if (j < 3)`.  Don't bury the condition in the loop's termination condition.

Answer (score 1):

1. I recommend to format the brackets differently (the opening curly bracket on the same line). This saves some vertical space and the code is more legible.
2. I changed your code slightly: I added methods to improve legibility and changed the if statements into inline ones (again, to reduce vertical space needed and hence improve readability).

   ```
   private void printHorizontalLine() {
       for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
           System.out.print((i % 3 == 0) ? "+" : "-");
       }
   }

   private void printCells() {
       for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
           System.out.print((i % 3 == 0) ? "|" : " ");
       }
   }

   void MakingShapes() {
       for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
           this.printHorizontalLine();
           System.out.println();
           this.printCells();
           System.out.println();
       }
       this.printHorizontalLine();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To make it a better code, the first thing you should learn is to make it *reusable* through private methods: For example, you should code a private method to print the "+--+--+--+" sequence, and another one to print the "|  |  |  |" sequence.

Once achieved this, you'll need *just one loop*, with no IFs, to produce the required shape. And, at the end, you'll have to invoke once more the "+--+--+--+" method.

Try this way and realize how you'll produce a shorter, easy to read and maintain program.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question like this one and I'll try you said.